# How to embed external images into a PDF file using CakePDF and Dompdf?

Tags: pdf, cakephp, dompdf, cakephp-3.4

I'm using `CakePHP 3.4` and `CakePdf` to generate pdf files using `domPdf` plugin.

also using `QrCode` plugin to generate QR Code on the go.

I want to use generated QR Code in my pdf file without saving them on disk.

This is what I have done

**FileDownloadController.php**

```
public function view($username = null)
{
    $this->loadModel('Users');

    $user = $this->Users->find()
        ->where(['Users.username' => $username])
        ->contain([])
        ->first();

    $this->viewBuilder()->options([
        'pdfConfig' => [
            'filename' => 'profplus_file_'.$user->id.'.pdf',
        ]
    ]);

    $this->set('user', $user);
}

public function generateQR($user_id)
{
    $this->autoRender = false;

    $this->loadModel('Users');

    $user = $this->Users->get($user_id);

    $string = Router::url('/', true) . 'q' . DS . $user->id;;
    $qrCode = new QrCode($string);
    $qrCode
    ->setSize(100);

    // Create a response object
    $response = $this->response;
    $response = $response->withType($qrCode->getContentType(PngWriter::class))
    ->withStringBody($qrCode->writeString(PngWriter::class));

    return $response;
}
```

**and in the view of pdf `pdf/view.ctp`**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="left-section">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="top-name">
                        <?= $user->first_name .' '. $user->last_name ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="top-address">
                        <i class="fa3 fa-phone"></i> <?= $user->mobile ?> | <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>: <?= $user->email ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td class="right-section">
            <img src="<?= $this->Url->build(['prefix' => false, 'controller' => 'ResumeDownload', 'action' => 'generateQR', $user->id], true) ?>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**But this is not adding the QR Code to the generated pdf file and shows error as**
[image]

using same code in direct view (without pdf generation), QR code is rendered on screen.

**How can I use the rendered response directly in a pdf file?**

> Edit 2

**CakePdf plugin configuration**

```
Configure::write('CakePdf', [
    'engine' => 'CakePdf.DomPdf',
    'margin' => [
        'bottom' => 15,
        'left' => 50,
        'right' => 30,
        'top' => 45
    ],
    'orientation' => 'potrait',
    'download' => false,
    'options' => [
        'isRemoteEnabled' => true,
    ],
]);
```

Comment: Have you [**enabled `allow_url_fopen`**](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Requirements#optional-configuration) and checked whether you may need to [**configure the HTTP context**](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Usage#sethttpcontext)?

Comment: `allow_url_fopen` is set to `on` http://profplus.in/info.php

Comment: I'm adding image generated from the same server. Will it be called to be external image, as you have edited title of the question?

Comment: Yes it will, from the point of view of Dompdf, all non-local filesystem paths are external/remote content. Have you checked the second link regarding context? Also have you enabled the `enable_remote` or `is_remote_enabled` option? **https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1118**

Comment: Yes, since I'm using `CakePdf` plugin which is further using `DomPdf` engine. I have included `isRemoteEnabled` set to `true` in configuration. Please see `Edit 2`

Comment: Check for possible warnings after rendering the PDF: `global $_dompdf_warnings; debug($_dompdf_warnings);`. Also what version of Dompdf are you using?

Comment: `CakePdf` version `3.2.3` and `DomPdf` version `0.8.0`

Comment: Thanks ndm, I somewhat solved it. I think the issue was there with configuration. adding `options` inside `engine` made it work

Comment: Ah, I overlooked that...